# Spring Change Transaction Isolation Mode

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-transactions, transactional

I want to change the transaction isolation mode to serializable with Spring annotation but I get an exception :

`@Transactional(isolation = Isolation.SERIALIZABLE)`

```
org.springframework.transaction.InvalidIsolationLevelException:
JtaTransactionManager does not support custom isolation levels by default - switch 'allowCustomIsolationLevels' to 'true'
```

I'm using the Atomikos transaction manager.

Is it possible to do it with the Spring Boot application.properties file? Otherwise how do it in Java (I don't want to use an xml configuration)?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found this solution for resolving the exception `(IllegalStateException: No JTA UserTransaction available - specify either 'userTransaction' or 'userTransactionName' or 'transactionManager' or 'transactionManagerName')` :

```
@Bean(initMethod = "init", destroyMethod = "close")
public UserTransactionManager atomikosTransactionManager() {
    UserTransactionManager userTransactionManager = new UserTransactionManager();
    userTransactionManager.setForceShutdown(false);

    return userTransactionManager;
}

@Bean
public UserTransaction atomikosUserTransaction() throws SystemException {
    UserTransactionImp userTransaction = new UserTransactionImp();
    userTransaction.setTransactionTimeout(300);

    return userTransaction;
}

@Bean
public PlatformTransactionManager platformTransactionManager() throws SystemException {
    JtaTransactionManager jtaTransactionManager = new JtaTransactionManager();

    jtaTransactionManager.setTransactionManager(atomikosTransactionManager());
    jtaTransactionManager.setUserTransaction(atomikosUserTransaction());
    jtaTransactionManager.setAllowCustomIsolationLevels(true);

    return jtaTransactionManager;
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Has anyone a better solution?

Answer (score 1):

You can customize and override default Jta transaction manager  one used by spring boot

```
@Bean public PlatformTransactionManager platformTransactionManager() {
 JtaTransactionManager manager = new JtaTransactionManager()
   manager.setAllowCustomIsolationLevels(true);
 return manager ; }
```

Comment: With this solution I will keep an Atomikos transaction manager?

Comment: I get an exception with this solution : 
`org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'platformTransactionManager'`
`Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No JTA UserTransaction available - specify either 'userTransaction' or 'userTransactionName' or 'transactionManager' or 'transactionManagerName'`
Do you know what's wrong ?